# How to handle multiple websocket endpoints in VueJS + Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, vuex

I have a WebSocket server with multiple endpoints, like this:

- /scale
- /machineStatus
- /worker

I want to handle messages from the server based on the endpoints they came from. So I want to handle messages from /scale differently than messages from /machineStatus.

I'm not sure how to do this correctly. My current approach is to create a WebSocket client for each endpoint in my App.vue:

```
mounted() {
    // scale endpoint
    var socket_scale = new WebSocket("ws://10.50.25.1:8104/scale");

    socket_scale.onopen = function() {
        this.$store.dispatch('websocket/setSocketOpen', source);
    }.bind(this);

    socket_scale.onclose = function() {
        this.$store.dispatch('websocket/setSocketClose', source);
    }.bind(this);


    socket_scale.onmessage = function(event) {
        this.$store.dispatch('websocket/setSocketMessage', [event, source]);
    }.bind(this);

    socket_scale.onerror = function(event) {
        this.$store.dispatch('websocket/setSocketError', [event, source]);
    }.bind(this)
    // machine_status endpoint
    var socket_machine_status = new WebSocket("ws://10.50.25.1:8104/machine_status");

    socket_machine_status.onmessage = function(event) {
        this.$store.dispatch('websocket/setSocketMessage', [event, source]);
    }.bind(this);
    // worker endpoint
    var socket_worker = new WebSocket("ws://10.50.25.1:8104/worker");

    socket_worker.onmessage = function(event) {
        this.$store.dispatch('websocket/setSocketMessage', [event, source]);
    }.bind(this);
}
```

In my websocket store component, I can discriminate between messages based on the source parameter. The store component would look something like this:

```
const state = {
    isConnected: false,
    message_scale: {},
    message_machine_status: {},
    message_worker: {}
};

const actions = {
    setSocketOpen({ commit }) {
        commit('SOCKET_ONOPEN');
    },
    setSocketClose({ commit }) {
        commit('SOCKET_ONCLOSE');
    },
    setSocketMessage({ commit }, params) {
        commit('SOCKET_ONMESSAGE', params);
    },
    setSocketError({ commit }, event) {
        commit('SOCKET_ONERROR', event.data);
    }
}

const mutations = {
    SOCKET_ONOPEN(state) {
        console.info("WebSocket connected");
        state.isConnected = true;
    },
    SOCKET_ONCLOSE(state) {
        state.isConnected = false;
    },
    SOCKET_ONERROR(state, event) {
        console.error(state, event);
    },
    SOCKET_ONMESSAGE(state, params) {

        switch (params[1]) {
            case "scale" : state.message_scale = params[0]; break;
            case "machine_status" : state.message_machine_status = params[0]; break;
            case "worker" : state.message_worker = params[0]; break;
            default: break;
        }
    },
    SOCKET_RECONNECT_ERROR(state) {
        state.reconnectError = true;
    }
};

const getters = {
    message (state) {
        return state.message;
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters
}
```

It's a bit verbose, but it could work. I have the different messages in different state objects.
Is there a more elegant way to do this?